# Removing a record from DbSet throws "Value cannot be null" error in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have the following code to remove a membership from the `GroupMemberships` DbSet, which is quite straightforward:

```
public int RemoveStudentFromGroup(string studentId, int groupId)
{
    try
    {
        var member = _context.GroupMemberships
                             .Where(pgm => pgm.UserId == studentId && pgm.StudentGroupId == groupId)
                             .FirstOrDefault();

        _context.GroupMemberships.Remove(member);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        return 1;
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

However, for some reason (after upgrading from EF Core 2.2 to 3.0), this code throws the following error:

> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'entity')
>
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Utilities.Check.NotNull[T](T value,
> String parameterName)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.Remove(TEntity
> entity)
> at Synergy.Controllers.StudentGroupController.RemoveStudentFromGroup(String
> studentId, Int32 groupId) in C:\Users\ErkanEr\source\repos\Synergy\Controllers\StudentGroupController.cs:line 810
> at lambda_method623(Closure , Object , Object[] )

Here is the definition of the `GroupMembership` entity:

```
public class GroupMembership
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("StudentGroupId")]
    public StudentGroup StudentGroup { get; set; }
    public int StudentGroupId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
}
```

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: Did you check if member != null ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to check if `member` is null before calling .Remove()